# Python в обработке геоданных

Tags: python

Необходимо построить в Python профиль местности между двумя географическими точками. Затем визуализировать этот участок. Какие лучше использовать источники географических карт, и какие форматы лучше подходят - векторные или растровые?

Comment: Рекомендую взглянуть сюда:
https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-latlontools-plugin

Comment: А как это должно выглядеть? Что нужно отобразить? Перепады высоты? Если да, то посмотрите на matplotlib. Он позволяет строить графики. В данном случае, можно представить вашу местность как кривую и отобразить там ее

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы подготовить профиль местности между двумя географическими точками необходимо:

1. отобразить на карте с помощью линии (прямой или ломанной) месторасположение вашей местности и как её "режет" профиль (средств миллион, смотрите, что вам ближе, может быть это окажется создание kml и отображение его в Google Earth, карта в qgis, arcgis, leaflet.js, в питоне geoplot, googlemaps, и прочее).
2. создать график отражающий свойства профиля (matplotlib, модули для excel).
3. автоматизированно сверстать документ для презентации карты и профиля с подписями, масштабами и пр. - работа с шаблонами, pdf-ами, xml-ками и т.п.

На значительное количество вопросов по поводу ГИС сможете найти ответы на сайтах:

http://gis-lab.info/

http://qgis.org/ru/site/

http://www.gdal.org/

http://postgis.net/

Также отмечу хороший ресурс от коммерческой ГИС для ознакомления:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/ru/arcmap/ - там же можете скачать пробную версию и "по-тыкать" основные функции.